# Find high and low between two points

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How can I get the ceiling and the floor between them by having number two candlesticks?
For example, between candle number 1000 and candle number 1020.

Answer (score 0):

`bar_index` will tell you the current bar index. You can use that to figure out if your are within your window, and create two variables to keep track of the high and low price.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)
bot = input.int(1000)
top = input.int(1020)

var float hi = 10e-10
var float lo = 10e10

bool window = bar_index >= bot and bar_index <= top

if (window)
    if (high > hi)
        hi := high
        
    if (low < lo)
        lo := low
        
plot(window ? hi : na, color=color.green)
plot(window ? lo : na, color=color.red)
```

Answer (score -1):

I’m not really sure what you mean when saying “ceiling” and “floor”, but if you meant getting the highest and lowest, than you can use this tutorial:

https://kodify.net/tradingview/bar-data/highest-high-lowest-low/

Keep in mind that this tutorial referring to earlier versions of pinscript, so you’ll need to refer to highest() as ta.highest() and lowest() as ta.lowest() on current version 5.

Comment: This tutorial does not show how to get the highest and lowest values between two bars. If he uses those functions, the values will always be updated unless he adds a check for the `bar_index`.